# How to remove extra space in comment line in XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

How to remove extra spaces from comment line using lxml

I had tried commenting a Necessary tag using following code:

```
tc.getparent().replace(tc,etree.Comment(etree.tostring(tc)))
print(etree.tostring(doc2).decode())
```

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
                <!--<Necessary/>
                -->
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
                <!--<Necessary/>
                -->
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
```

i have already tried with beautifulsoup but spaces are still there in comment

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('XML1.xml', 'r'), 'xml')

    for elem in soup.find_all():
        if elem.string is not None:
            elem.string = elem.string.strip()
```

required XML is as follows:

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
                <!--<Necessary/>-->
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
                <!--<Necessary/>-->
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
```

My problem is with extra new line in tag: Necessary/> and  "-->" where "-->" is going to next line .

Any help would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "extra" new line after the comment belongs to the element used as comment text. So this string already contains the extra withespace including the next element indent
`etree.tostring(ele)`

Keeping that tail text and applying to the Comment fixes the issue.

```
>>> doc = etree.parse('test.xml')
>>> for ele in doc.xpath('//Necessary'):
...     t = ele.tail
...     c = etree.Comment(etree.tostring(ele, with_tail=False))
...     c.tail = t
...     ele.getparent().replace(ele, c)
... 
>>> print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Result

```
<List>
  <Item>
    <Price>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
      <Next_Item>
        <Name>Apple</Name>
        <!--<Necessary/>-->
      </Next_Item>
      <Next_Item>
        <Name>Orange</Name>
        <!--<Necessary/>-->
      </Next_Item>
    </Price>
  </Item>
</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select all comments by invoke `Comment` and replace them by a stripped version:

```
for c in soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    c.replace_with(Comment(c.strip()))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment

xml = '''
<List>
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
                <!--<Necessary/>
                -->
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
                <!--<Necessary/>
                -->
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
for c in soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    c.replace_with(Comment(c.strip()))
soup
```

##### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List>
<Item>
<Price>
<Amount>100</Amount>
<Next_Item>
<Name>Apple</Name>
<!--<Necessary/>-->
</Next_Item>
<Next_Item>
<Name>Orange</Name>
<!--<Necessary/>-->
</Next_Item>
</Price>
</Item>
</List>
```